# Ratios and Fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to assist my daughter with holiday work, please help me with these questions:

Q1: Find the ratio $a:b$, when  $\frac{a+b}{a-b}=\frac{11}{5}$

Q2: Find the the ratio $a:b:c$ when   $\frac{1}{c}=\frac{2}{3b}=\frac{3}{4a}$

Q3: Evaluate $\frac{3a-b}{a+2b}$ if $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{4}{5}$

Comment: Benny, please consider using parenthesis to help clarify what is on the top and bottom of the fractions, otherwise things get ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

For the first, try to get things in terms of the quantity $x=a/b$. Use the fact that $r+s$ can be written as $s(\frac{r}{s}+1)$, which you can verify by multiplying it out.
$$\frac{11}{5}=\frac{b\left(\frac{a}{b}+1\right)}{b\left(\frac{a}{b}-1\right)}=\frac{x+1}{x-1}.$$
Solve this for $x$.

For the second, take the reciprocal:
$$c=\frac{3}{2}b=\frac{4}{3}a.$$

For the third, again, try to get things in terms of $x=a/b=4/5$.
$$\frac{3a-b}{a+2b}=\frac{b\left(3\frac{a}{b}-1\right)}{b\left(\frac{a}{b}+2\right)}=\frac{3\cdot\frac{4}{5}-1}{\frac{4}{5}+2}.$$

Note that all three of Ragnar's answers are wrong at the time of this post, so don't be alarmed if your answers don't match his.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Find the ratio a:b, when $ \dfrac{a+b}{a−b}=\dfrac{11}{5}$
Ans : $ \dfrac{a+b+a-b}{a+b-a+b}=\dfrac{11+5}{11-5}$ => $ \dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{8}{3}$

Q2 : Q2: Find the the ratio a:b:c when $ \dfrac{1}{c}=\dfrac{2}{3b}=\dfrac{3}{4a} $

Ans : $\dfrac{1}{c}=\dfrac{2}{3b} $ => $\dfrac{b}{c}=\dfrac{2}{3} $ =>$ b:c = 2:3 $ 
Again $\dfrac{2}{3b}=\dfrac{3}{4a} $ => $ \dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{3*3}{2*4} $ = > $ a:b = 9:8 $

$ b:c = 8: 12 $ So $ a:b:c = 9:8:12 $

Question 3: Evaluate $ \dfrac{3a−b}{a+2b} \text{ if } \dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{4}{5} $ => $ a =\dfrac{4b}{5} $

Therefore , $ \dfrac{3a−b}{a+2b}  = \dfrac{\dfrac{12b}{5}-b}{\dfrac{4b}{5}+2b} =  \dfrac{\dfrac{7b}{5}}{\dfrac{14b}{5}}  = \dfrac{1}{2} $

Answer (score 0):

For the first, start by cross-multiplying:  $5(a+b)=11(a-b)$.  Moving all the $b$'s to the left side and all the $a$'s to the right, you have $16b=6a$, so $a/b=16/6=8/3$.

For the second, break it up into two problems, finding $a/b$ and $a/c$.  Solve each the way you solved the first.

Answer (score -1):

Q1: You can rewrite this to $5(a-b)=11(a+b)$, and thus $-6a=16 b$. It follows that $\frac ab=-\frac 38$.

Q2: Take the inverse: $c=\frac 32 b=\frac 43 a$, thus $a:b:c=\frac 34:\frac 23:1$.

Q3: $\frac{3a-b}{a+2b}=\frac{2\frac ab-1}{\frac ab+2}=\frac{2\frac 45-1}{\frac 45+2}=\frac{\frac 35}{\frac {14}5}=\frac 3{14}$

Comment: Did the ratios get flipped somewhere in Q$2$?

Comment: You're right, changed it.